# "It had to be (someone) vs. "it had to have been (someone)" when drawing conclusions

Tags: grammar, difference

It's said that the grammar structure *had to have done* can be used instead of *must have done* when drawing a conclusion about a past event. For example:

> You said somebody played the piano 6 pm yesterday. **It had to have been Kate**. She always does.

But, I've heard people say it *had to be* instead of *it had to have been*, it seems, in the same way. For example:

> You said somebody played the piano 6 pm yesterday. **It had to be Kate**. She always does.

Is there any difference in meaning between *it had to be* and *it had to have been* when drawing conclusions about past events?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference and it can be a little confusing.

> You said somebody played the piano 6 pm yesterday. **It had to have been Kate**. She always does.

This means you can't think of anyone else who might have been playing the piano at that time.

> You said somebody played the piano 6 pm yesterday. **It had to be Kate.** She always does.

Most people would take this to mean the same thing, but native speakers would usually say "**That** had to be Kate."

"It had to be" can also mean there was a requirement at the time.

> Both Kate and Paul are great piano players, I wonder why they picked Kate?
> It had to be Kate because they needed someone who could also play the flute and Paul can't do that.